# How do I have my program's core dump saved to a file upon a crash?

Tags: linux, coredump

I'm using Bash. I used `ulimit -c unlimited` but the program still doesn't generate a core file. It may be due to the GUI debugger kicking in. I get the option to save the crash info to a file, but I really want a core file.

Edit: I just wrote a small non-gui program meant to crash, and it produced a core dump.

Comment: can you prevent the GUI debugger from kicking in?

Comment: Have you ran it directly from the commandline with no GUI involved, does that get you a core file?

Comment: It's whatever comes with Fedora. I don't know if I can disable it. I really don't want to disable it globally though. It is only started with GUI programs when they crash.

Comment: @Vinko: Yes, I'm programming and starting it all in a bash shell.

Comment: @Scott: But does that get you a core file?

Comment: @Vinko: No, or I wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: Some distributions customize `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` to send core dumps to an executable which handles crashes.  Can you check that?

Comment: @ephemient: That file has 'core' in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to run your app from the command line within gdb:

```
gdb --args /path/to/program with args
```

I assume the program that's causing you problems is Bug Buddy? You can always remove it or tweak your program to reset the default SIGSEGV handle to SIG_DFL after the GTK start-up to ensure the OS catches the signal and not any magic handling by the GUI libraries.